# CSRF for Java EE Aplication - JSF (No Spring Framework)

Tags: java, csrf

I'm working in a Java EE application with JSF and Primefaces Framework and I need to add some kind of CSRF attack protection. I read about OWASP CSRF Guard but I really don't understand how to implement it into my project and I saw lot of codes using Spring Framework too, but I would like to avoid the implementation of that framework in my project (besides I don't know anything about Spring).

If anyone can help me about how to proceed with this problem or maybe some documentation that I should read or anything to help I will be really thankful.

Comment: Did you look at the Related questions section (4th one, 57 upvotes)? There's an 11yo post on preventing CSRF in JSF, along with XSS and others...

Comment: Hello Boris, thanks for the answer. I've read the post and I would like to give some extra information about the problem. I'm working with WildFly 10.0.1Final and I really did anything to protect my application of CSRF attacks, I put some http headers as x-content-type-options, x-frame-options, x-xss-protection, even I updated my faces-config.xml and added the "protected views" tag to match any .xhtml in my web application but I'm still getting CSRF vulnerabilities from OWASP - ZAP. I really don't understand how to make my application safer from those attacks.

Comment: I would like to add that I implemented a code that adds a Cipher phrase to the HTTPSession and using WebFilters I read that information and validate the content, but I'm still getting the same problem.